# Recover Windows user folder

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, data-recovery

Someone's Windows install decided to continuously fail to sign in, and long story short, I made a change to the registry that *should* have worked, or at least should not have *deleted their user folder and made a new one.*
It did that. Because screw logic.

So I wanted to try recovering that folder and reinstalling Windows. But there are a few issues in my way.

1. I've been limited to a laptop with a single drive slot until two days ago. **This happened a few months ago.** I'm worried some or all of the data may be overwritten/corrupted. Not much I can do about that.
2. **I need to recover their data from Remix OS** before reinstalling, since Remix OS lives on the Windows partition. In fact, it's probably more important that I back that up, but I have yet to find Remix's user data directory.
3. I can't just do a recovery on the whole partition. Their drive is a really slow WD Slim, which happens to hold **an entire terabyte**. I can't just image their 900+GB Windows partition. I don't have a 1TB drive anywhere aside from this one.

Edit: I forgot to mention something really important. The reason I wanted to reinstall Windows is because the issue that caused the wipe has also either made the OS useless or bricked it. I can't remember, it's been a while.

Comment: Unless you can't run a recovery on the entire partition I think there is no way to specifically target the files you are looking for. Unless you know exactly on which sectors/blocks the data resides.

Comment: Ouch. I don't even know the names of the files. I have nowhere to save the data. So... the Windows data is good as gone?

Comment: I actually have an idea. Do you want to perform the recovery from within windows or remix OS? I'm not sure if it will work under remix OS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Windows doesn't boot on that device right now. And Remix OS is doing weird crap like not letting me keep a terminal open and seemingly restarting every minute or so. Also, I already have the drive out of the laptop and connected to my PC, and it's a pain to remove the drive from that laptop, so I'd rather not have to do it again, anyways. Though I can do it from my Windows install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get a working windows or linux install (no huge space requirement) I suggest `testdisk`.

Testdisk runs on windows and linux and has a great feature called "undelete". Please note that this only works with files which have been marked as deleted on the filesystem, if the data was already overwritten regular file-recovery is your only choice as far as I know.

Once you got [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), run it as administrator or root. Hit `Create`. Then select the desired disk. The partition type is most likely `Intel`,
choosing the default is generally safe. After that go to `Advanced`. Your windows NTFS partition should show, select it in the list and go to `Undelete`.

On the next screen, you should see all directories and files that were deleted in the past and not overwritten yet. If you can find your folder/files there, you can simply hit `:` to select the files/folders you want to save followed by `C` to copy all selected files to a destination of your choice.

Comment: I already have testdisk... probably from a previous incident. This seem to be what I needed, but is there any way to change how it orders files? I can't figure out how it's ordering them, but there are a LOT of files on the list. I guess on a 1TB drive it takes a long time before deleted files actually have to be overwritten... it's showing Minecraft object files deleted in 2016. I forgot that the laptop was that old.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an option to sort that list, what you *could* do is use `a` to select and undelete all the files and then sort them later, that sounds a bit easier to me.

Comment: Will I have to save them to a different drive, or does it just add pointers back to all of them?

Comment: Neither. It copies the files to a destination you choose, but it can be on the same drive.

Comment: I'm guessing it doesn't keep directory structures...

Comment: You could give https://www.pandorarecovery.com a try, it claims to preserve that. However I have never used that and I'm unsure if it works.

Comment: Would the (number).png files be images it couldn't find the name of, or are they more likely to be files used by a program that originally had those names? Also I just now realized the scroll wheel works in testdisk...

Comment: It does, so does pagination with the page-up/down keys. For the two drives I tested this on it always gave me original filenames, so I'm gussing those are the original file names, I'd give a few a try and see for yourself though.